# Как сделать обновление по неделям в телеграмм боте(python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Хотелось бы сделать так, что-бы каждую неделю автоматически обновлялся список охранников, дежурящих в эту неделю.
То есть если прошла неделя - новые данные.
Как можно такое организовать?
Библиотека: PyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: А вы хотя бы питались это сделать самостоятельно? Или же вы надеетесь что вам тут скинут готовый код просто так?

Comment: Да, пытался, не хватает знаний, а нужно срочно